# regex catch the 'end tag on html'

Tags: php, regex, match

I have this regex which cathes **tags** on html but the problem is it won't catch the last end tag.

REGEX:
`(<[^>]*value=")month("[^>]*>)([^<]*)(<[^>]*>)`

HTML TAG:
`<option value="month">MONTH</option></select>`

i don't know how to catch the `</select>` tag. I tried putting another `(<[^>]*>)` which result from **no match found** in the html.

HERE'S the [LINK](http://regex101.com/r/lR4gG3) where I test my regex. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have forgotten the newline between `</option>`and `</select>`

You must add `\s*` *(or `\n` if you are sure that the newline is the only white space)*:

```
(<[^>]*value=")month("[^>]*>)([^<]*)(<[^>]*>)\s*(<[^>]*>)
```

But what are you trying to do?

[about character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)

Comment: im trying to catch those tags on html and make a duplicate for the `option tag`

Comment: @Darline: in other words, you want two `<option value="month"....</option>` at the end, before the closing "select" tag?